# C# Creating global number which increase by 1

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am writing simple bank account tutorial program. For each new customer which enrolls, the account number will be incremented by 1, for a new id.
I saw example in "C# Mueller" book. I am just curious if this is proper way to conduct this, how will it handle concurrency enrollments? Is there a better to handle this, maybe with Singletons or global variables, memory cache? How would item like this be handled in real world application?

```
public class BankAccount
{
    private static int _nextAccountNumber = 1000;
    private int _accountNumber;

    private double _balance;

    public void InitBankAccount()
    {
        _accountNumber = ++_nextAccountNumber;
        _balance = 0.0;
    }

    public void Deposit(decimal amount) 
    {
        _balance += amount;
    }
    etc...
```

This site is also useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: You can easily test it and prove that your code is not reliable. i.e.:
`Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000), i => { new BankAccount().InitBankAccount(); });
Assert.AreEqual(2000, BankAccount._nextAccountNumber);`. After that, you could use a [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) on the increment operation to acquire mutual exclusion.

Comment: When you restart your application, the counting restarts. A real life app stores the generated numbers in a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is ok, but not thread safe.  thepirat000 mentioned in a comment that you could use a lock statement.

```
private static object acctNumLock = new object();
…
lock(acctnumLock) { 
    _accountNumber = ++_nextAccountNumber;
    }
```

You should also consider using the [Interlock.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Interlocked_Increment_System_Int32__) method which is more efficient.  The lock statement allows you to 'lock' (allow only one thread access at a time) to a block of statements.  The Interlock.Increment is an atomic operation, that only does one thing (namely increment a value), but does so in a way that ensures the operation is completed before the thread switches.  Both provide thread safety.

Is there a better way?  That's a very difficult question to answer because it depends on what you are trying to do.  I suspect that actual banking applications take out DB locks and use specific algorithms to generate account numbers (i.e. a much more complicated process).  If you are just trying to generate unique values for simple applications what you have should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netcore-2.1) here, which returns the incremented amount.  It should be thread safe, there's an example in the docs link that uses it for that purpose.

```
using System.Threading;

... 

public void InitBankAccount()
{
    _accountNumber = Interlocked.Increment(ref _nextAccountNumber);
    _balance = 0.0;
}
```