# Interlocked.Increment Method by a Certain Number Interval

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

We have a concurrent, multithreaded program.
How would I make a sample number increase by +5 interval every time? Does Interlocked.Increment, have an overload for interval? I don't see it listed.

[Microsoft Interlocked.Increment Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Interlocked_Increment_System_Int32__)

```
// Attempt to make it increase by 5

private int NumberTest;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    NumberTest= Interlocked.Increment(ref NumberTest);
}
```

This is another question its based off,

[C# Creating global number which increase by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740254/c-sharp-creating-global-number-which-increase-by-1)

Comment: Yes, but the increase by five is not atomic; it's possible that when you are finished, someone else might have decremented (or incremented) the same number while you were incrementing. Only the read, increment by one operation is atomic

Comment: @Flydog `Add` is atomic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`Interlocked.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Adds two integers and replaces the first integer with the sum, as an atomic operation.

```
int num = 0;
Interlocked.Add(ref num, 5);
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding (i.e `+=`) is not and cannot be an atomic operation (as you know). Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this without enforcing a full fence, on the bright-side these are fairly optimised at a low level. However, there are several other ways you can ensure integrity though (especially since this is just an add)

1. The use of `Interlocked.Add` (The sanest solution)
2. Apply exclusive `lock` (or `Moniter.Enter`) outside the for loop.
3. `AutoResetEvent` to ensure threads doing task one by one (meh *sigh*).
4. Create a temp `int` in each thread and once finished add temp onto the sum under an exclusive lock or similar.
5. The use of `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.
6. `Parallel.For` thread based accumulation with `Interlocked.Increment` sum, same as 4.

Comment: @GregThomas582 it will worknand fairly light weight, however there other options that was worthy of an additional answer